# Weird Buzzy Static Sound on Headphones?

Tags: sound, headphones

I've been having this issue for a few weeks now. Every time I plug in headphones or speakers into the audio jack I get this weird static noise. I can still hear the music and audio, but when I pause it there's this noticeable buzzy or static sound.

I've Googled it a bunch of times and tried a few different methods to solve it. There's are the ones I tried last time:

1. Some people suggest using AlsaMixer to fix it, but I don't seem to have all of the options the solution recommends.
2. Entering `pulseaudio --check`, `pulseaudio --k`, `pulseaudio --D` turns off the sound, but when I unplug & replug it's back to the same issue.
3. Entering `killall speech-dispatcher`, which does nothing.

Any idea what else I could try?

**System details**:

- **Dell Laptop**: XPS 13 9350
- **Operating System**: Ubuntu 19.04 disco (x86-64)
- **Cinnamon Version**: 4.0.9
- **Linux Kernel**: 5.0.0-32-generic
- **Processor**: Intel Core i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz x 2
- **Memory**: 7.7 GiB
- **Hard Drives**: 125.1 GB
- **Graphics Card**: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 (HD Graphics 520)
- **Service Tag**: 1QCB562
- **Express Service Code**: 3769578218

https://www.dell.com/support/home/ca/en/cabsdt1/product-support/servicetag/0-SGpLZEhQVlpnTVFjYkU1VjRFemNQdz090/overview

Comment: Please advise the make of your PC, and the model number from the serial number sticker underneath or on the back. Click [edit] and add that useful info into your original question. Please do not use Add Comment, but instead click [edit].

Comment: @K7AAY I found a work-around, but it's not great. In Alsamixer I set Master to 46, Headphone to 100, Headphone (next one) to 22, Speaker to 49, and PCM to 100. I can't change Mic Mute. These are on; S/PDIF, S/PDIF 1, S/PIDF 2, S/PDIF 3, S/PDIF 4. Auto-Mute is Enabled. Headset Mi is 0, and Interal M is 0. If I adjust sound with built-in controls (ie: YouTube) then it works without static. BUT if I adjust the volume with keyboard buttons the static comes back. :( Also I'm on very lowest audio setting, increasing volume +1 is VERY loud. And sets things in Alsamixer to 100.